# Flutter: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, api, flutter, http, dart

I need to fetch data from API but my try-catch fails with SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Code:

```
    String problems;
     try {
         final response = await http.get('http://myURL',headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      log("after http");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        problems = data["IsSuccess"];
        return problems.toString();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load status data');
      }
    } catch (exc) {
      log("catch:" + exc.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: You got the error because your api returned html not json.

Answer (score 2):

NetService:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class NetService {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';

class IOT {
  List data;

  FutureOr<void> fetchMeasurements() async {
    await NetService.getJson<Map<String, dynamic>>('http://iot.productio.net/api/Measurement/GetMeasurements')
      .then((response) {
        data = (response != null && response['IsSuccess'])
          ? response['Entity']
          : null;
      })
      .whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done!....'));
  }
}
void main(List<String> args) async {
  var iot = IOT();
  await iot.fetchMeasurements();
  print(iot.data.take(3).toString());
}
```

Result:

```
Fetching done!....
({Id: 21315, MeasurementDate: 2021-02-18T22:06:20.8365195, Temperature: 20.6, Humidity: 36.8, Misto: loznice}, {Id: 21314, MeasurementDate: 2021-02-18T22:01:19.1337516, Temperature: 20.6, Humidity: 37.0, Misto: loznice}, {Id: 21313, MeasurementDate: 2021-02-18T21:56:18.1720883, Temperature: 20.6, Humidity: 36.9, Misto: loznice})
```

Comment: Please include some explanation with your answer.

Comment: I created a new project just with your code
This appears:

`Restarted application in 11 308ms.

XMLHttpRequest error.

Fetching done!....

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(dartx.take)' of null
    at main$ (http://localhost:54159/packages/jsontest/main.dart.lib.js:91:40)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    ....

`

Comment: This seems to be an error from your configuration. **(1)** Check if you can get response from `http://iot.productio.net/api/Measurement/GetMeasurements` in your browser, **(2)** What's your system info?, **(3)** Have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516300/flutter-http-package-is-not-responding)?

Answer (score -1):

First encode your Data after sending time convert it into toString() like HashMap.toString().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).