# How to solve flutter apps http request error

Tags: flutter, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to show data from my Mysql using http request. But data is not getting in my app and showing errors.
I followed some tutorials from the very beginning but having the same problem while fetching

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:test_project/constants/strings.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:test_project/models/categoryData.dart';

class API_Manager {
  Future<Welcome> getData() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var categoryModel = null;

    var response = await http.get(
        'https://flutter-storebd.000webhostapp.com/flutter_food_app/api/config/getfood.php');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;

      var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
      var categoryModel = Welcome.fromJson(jsonMap);
    }

    return categoryModel;
  }
}
```

When I run that above code the error I'm getting is:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1612:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 152:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 704:44
handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 733:13
_propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 530:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37307:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:5345:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:39347:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:39341:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:39173:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:39179:13)
    at http://localhost:61409/dart_sdk.js:34686:9
```

Comment: Your problem is similar to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266936/flutter-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/66268218?noredirect=1#comment117195574_66268218) check it, please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use "Future" it has to return an object of type "Welcome", in your case it doesn't return anything when statusCode is different from 200 and also, you use variables that do not return, try to use this code:

The service:

```
class ApiManager {
  Future<Welcome> getData() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var categoryModel;

    try {
      var response = await client.get(
        'https://flutter-storebd.000webhostapp.com/flutter_food_app/api/config/getfood.php');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        print(jsonString);
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        categoryModel = Welcome.fromJson(jsonMap);
        return categoryModel;
      } else {
        // Other status code, you have to return anything
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Error when request is executed, you have to return anything
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The model:

```
class Welcome {
  Welcome({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.details,
  });

    String id;
    String title;
    String price;
    String details;

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        price: json["price"],
        details: json["details"],
       );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "price": price,
        "details": details,
      };
}
```

Comment: I don't know why was this answer marked as accepted but it has absolutely nothing to to with the issue

Comment: this answer does not answer the question. I had the same question myself.