# I want to import a part of a web page

Tags: flutter, http, dart, web

I want to bring the notice of the school homepage to my app.
but I don't know what the problem is.
I'd like to bring in Tag , link and day of the week, too.

here is my noticed.dart

```
class _HotNewsWidgetState extends State<HotNewsWidget> {
  List<String> title = List();
  List<String> post = List();
  List<String> link = List();
  void _getDataFromWeb() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/yongwon-h/main.do');
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ul_list');
    final element2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_more');
    final linkElemnt = document.getElementsByClassName('ul_list');
    setState(() {
      title = elements
          .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHtml)
          .toList();
      post = element2
          .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHtml)
          .toList();
      link = linkElemnt
          .map((element) =>
              element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes['href'])
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

here is School homepage html

```
<div class="notice060">
                    
                    <div class="list_box on">
                        <ul class="ul_list">

                        <li><a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85179304&amp;mi=73746">제8기 진해용원고등학교운영위원회 학부모위원 당선자 공고</a>
                            <span class="date">2021.03.19</span>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li><a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85156448&amp;mi=73746">20201학년도 대학수학능력시험 시행기본계획</a>
                            <span class="date">2021.03.17</span>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li><a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85141070&amp;mi=73746">제8기 학교운영위원회 교원위원 입후보자 등록현황</a>
                            <span class="date">2021.03.15</span>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li><a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85129816&amp;mi=73746">3월 3주 전학년 학사운영 안내</a>
                            <span class="date">2021.03.12</span>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85117819&amp;mi=73746">2021 찾아가는 교육정책 설명회</a>
                            <span class="date">2021.03.10</span>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
                
</div>
```

explanation
[homepage picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64YSt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class Yongwon {
  static const _url = 'http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/yongwon-h/main.do';
  static final _regExp1 = RegExp(r'<h2 class="tit_1">(.|\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029)*?<h2 class="tit_2">');
  static final _regExp2 = RegExp(r'<li><a.+>(.+)<\/a>(.|\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029)*?(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d)');

  static FutureOr<void> fetchNoticies() async {
    var page = await NetService.getRaw(_url).whenComplete(() => print('Page done.\n'));
    if (page != null) {
      final noticesPane = _regExp1.firstMatch(page)!.group(0);
      if (noticesPane != null) {
        final notices = _regExp2.allMatches(noticesPane);
        notices.forEach((notice) => print('${notice.group(1)} ..... ${notice.group(3)}'));
      }
    }
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await Yongwon.fetchNoticies();
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Result:

```
Page done.

제8기 진해용원고등학교운영위원회 학부모위원 당선자 공고 ..... 2021.03.19
20201학년도 대학수학능력시험 시행기본계획 ..... 2021.03.17
제8기 학교운영위원회 교원위원 입후보자 등록현황 ..... 2021.03.15
3월 3주 전학년 학사운영 안내 ..... 2021.03.12
2021 찾아가는 교육정책 설명회 ..... 2021.03.10

Job done!
```

Comment: thanks! bro, i want know networking.dart?

Comment: It is my own package with functions about HTTP requests, you can use `http` package instead

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?
Does the NetService you wrote over there match what you wrote?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266936/flutter-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/66268218#66268218

Comment: Dude, I said above you can use `http` package, that is, use `await http.get('http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/yongwon-h/main.do')`, my operation basically does that only.